# Can we use a hook_update_N for a module without hook_install?

Tags: 7, database, installation, updating

I am working on a custom module which does not have an install file but nevertheless uses a lot of tables. The one who worked on it previously, created the database tables manually. Now I want to add more tables to it. I could run the query manually to get the job done but I wanted to use the 'Drupal' way to do that. So I was wondering if we could use a hook_update_N for a module without hook_install?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No module needs to implement every hook. You can use hook_update_n() and not have a hook_install() function just fine.

You'll probably at 1 point want to define hook_schema() for these tables. An easy tool to get the "drupal" schema for **any** mysql table (already defined) in your mysql database is the [Schema module](http://drupal.org/project/schema).

> - Schema documentation: hyperlinked display of the schema's embedded
>     documentation explaining what each table and field is for.
> - **Schema
>     structure generation: the module examines the live database and
>     creates Schema API data structures for all tables that match the live
>     database.**
> - Schema comparison: the module compares the live database
>     structure with the schema structure declared by all enabled modules,
>     reporting on any missing or incorrect tables.
>
> **Note for MySQL users:**
>   The Schema module requires MySQL 5. Prior versions of MySQL do not
>   support the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database that the Schema module uses to
>   inspect the database.